# как округлить время до часов в ms sql

Tags: sql-server

допустим у меня есть таблица с числовыми данными и как мне из даты 04.07.2022 8:45 сделать 04:07.2022 9:00

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, Datetime), Datetime)
  ,Fe_value
  ,Smena
FROM [intermediatedb].[dbo].[Хим_анализ_1С] where datetime between '20220705 00:00' and '20220706 00:00'
  order by datetime
```

Comment: `04.07.2022 8:45` какой тип столбца у вас? это не особо похоже на `datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Округление до ближайшего часа:

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME2(0) = '2022-07-04 08:45:00'

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, @datetime), @datetime)
```

Из 60 вычитаем кол-во минут в дате и прибавляем к нашей дате.

Итог:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, "Datetime"), "Datetime") AS "Datetime"
       ,Fe_value
       ,Smena
FROM [intermediatedb].[dbo].[Хим_анализ_1С]
WHERE "Datetime" BETWEEN '2022-07-04' AND '2022-07-06'
ORDER BY "Datetime"
```

Comment: а такой запрос будет работать если вместо переменной брать значение из таблицы?

Comment: @xomul1 переменная не нужна, она для демонстрации, вместо "@datetime" в обоих местах подставь имя своего столбца так: DATEADD(MINUTE, 60 - DATEPART(MINUTE, [Имя столбца]), [Имя столбца]). Если ответ помог, отметь галочкой как принятый, ну и лайк приветствуется)

Comment: Когда я добавляю имя столбца, у меня значения столбца не округляются до следующего часа, а просто обнуляются минуты, то есть из '2022-07-04 08:45:00' становится '2022-07-04 08:00:00'

Comment: @xomul1 выложи свой запрос в вопрос, которым ты пытаешься выгрузить, я тебе исправлю его

Comment: выложил выложил!

Comment: @xomul1 дополнил ответ, попробуй запустить

Answer (score 0):

Возможно поможет

DECLARE @date As DateTime2

SET @date = '04.07.2022 8:45'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), @date, 120) --2022-07-04 8:45

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @date, 120) --2022-07-04 8

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: этак substring 13 могли бы сделать просто